# Vue + Vitest: Breakpoint Causes Shift in Stopping Position

Tags: vue.js, vite, vitest

## Issue to be Resolved

I am conducting operational verification of Vitest after executing "npm create vue@latest". The requirement is to set breakpoints within the  section of a Vue Single File Component (SFC) during unit test execution with Vitest, and to synchronize this with the VSCode debugger.

However, although the execution stops around the breakpoint and the debugger launches, the stopping position somehow shifts from its original location.

I am unable to determine the cause and would greatly appreciate any guidance.

Thank you very much for your assistance.

## Relevant Code / HelloWorld.vue

```js
<script lang="js">
import { defineComponent, reactive, computed, onMounted } from 'vue'

export default defineComponent({
  props: {
    msg: {
      type: String
    }
  },

  setup(props) {
    const state = reactive({
      count: 0
    })

    onMounted(() => {
      increment()
    })

    const increment = () => {
      // Assuming a breakpoint is set on the following line,
      state.count += 1
      console.log('HelloWorld.vue')
      console.log('HelloWorld.vue')
      console.log('HelloWorld.vue')
      // For some reason, it stops at the line below.
      console.log('HelloWorld.vue')
      console.log('HelloWorld.vue')
    }

    return {
      state,
      increment,
      uppercasedMessage: computed(() => props.message?.toUpperCase())
    }
  },
})
</script>
```

## vitest.config.js

It's almost in its initial state, with just the addition of a sourcemap.

```js
import { fileURLToPath } from 'node:url'
import { mergeConfig, defineConfig, configDefaults } from 'vitest/config'
import viteConfig from './vite.config'

export default mergeConfig(
  viteConfig,
  defineConfig({
    test: {
      environment: 'jsdom',
      exclude: [...configDefaults.exclude, 'e2e/*'],
      root: fileURLToPath(new URL('./', import.meta.url)),
      server: {
        sourcemap: true,
      }
    }
  })
)
```

## package.json

It's still in its initial state after running "npm create vue@latest".

```json
  "dependencies": {
    "pinia": "^2.1.7",
    "vue": "^3.4.15",
    "vue-router": "^4.2.5"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@playwright/experimental-ct-vue": "^1.41.1",
    "@playwright/test": "^1.41.1",
    "@rushstack/eslint-patch": "^1.3.3",
    "@vitejs/plugin-vue": "^5.0.3",
    "@vue/eslint-config-prettier": "^8.0.0",
    "@vue/test-utils": "^2.4.4",
    "eslint": "^8.49.0",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^9.17.0",
    "jsdom": "^24.0.0",
    "prettier": "^3.0.3",
    "vite": "^5.0.11",
    "vitest": "^1.2.2"
  }
```